# t-test to compare means: Small distances between means source of error?

Tags: t-test, mean

I am currently conducting a t-test with the following null/alternative hypothesis:

mean_a >= mean_b

mean_a < mean_b

As I failed to reject the null hypothesis I am looking for possible reasons for why that happened.
Looking at my sample data I realized the means of the sample are quite close together. mean_b is 17% higher than mean_a. For example compared to another hypothesis where I tested something similar, the age surplus was over 40%. I was able to reject the null hypothesis in that case.
Can the rather small distance between the means of the sample be a possible reason why I failed to reject the null hypothesis?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Yes, particularly if the variances of the two sample variances are large. You reject $H_0$ if the $T$-statistic is sufficiently less than 0. The numerator of $T$ is $\bar X_a - \bar X_b$, so if the two sample means are relatively close together, then you cannot reject. "Relatively" means relative to the size of the denominator, which depends on the sample variances. In general, the two sample means will not be exactly the same. The point of the test is to see if the distance between them is "statistically significant." If the sample means aren't sufficiently different, the answer is No.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! it was very helpful. do you mean by " if the variances of the two sample variances are large" that each variance by its one is large in comparison to the respective mean value?

Comment: Look at the formula for the $T$ statistic, you are using. If you are doing a pooled 2-sample t test, then the denominator uses a weighted average of the two sample variances, and the assumption is that the population variances are about equal. If you are doing a Welch separate variances t test the denominator of $T$ also involves both sample variances, but in a slightly different way. In both versions of the 2-sample t tests it is some combination of the two samp variances that matters. The larger the variances in the denom, the larger the diff in means in the numerator to declare signif.